# How to make a shell script pipe aware

Tags: command-line, scripts, pipe, sh, dash-shell

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ "${#}" -eq "0" ] && (printf "%s\\n" "${0}: word ..." >&2; exit 1)

_whats()
{
    [ -z "${1}" ] && return 1
    [ -z "${2}" ] && more_than_one="1"

    for word; do
        response="$(dig +short txt ${word}.wp.dg.cx)"
        printf "%s\\n" "${response}"
        if [ -z "${more_than_one}" ]; then
            printf "\\n%s\\n\\n" ":::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"
        fi
    done
}

_whats "${@}"
```

It works great when I call it this way:

```
whats shell\ script dns #it ouputs two definitions (shell script and dns)
```

However I'd also to call it this way:

```
echo shell\ script dns | whats
```

I'm just used to it, all other unix commands can do it, how would you implement it in a shell script?

Comment: And how would you handle `echo shell\ script dns | whats some\ other\ stuff foo`?

Comment: Last comment: `whats shell\ script dns` is actually shorter and easier to parse than `echo shell\ script dns | whats`. So why would you read stdin anyways?

Comment: I have a strange feeling I met this question somewhere else. And I asked the very same questions as @gniourf_gniourf.

Comment: @choroba you're right, it's still in [google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:UwLPlHEaleQJ:unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126605/how-to-make-a-shell-script-pipe-aware+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk) `:)`.

Comment: yes, I've plenty @gniourf_gniourf, sed, grep, cut, awk, xargs, all of them can take input from stdin, I want my scripts to be able to accept stdin as well. When I get stdin and parameters I'll parse both.

Comment: No, you're wrong. That's not how these tools work. Sorry, I don't have enough room in this margin to explain to you why, but believe me, that's not how they work. Actually I do have enough room to show you that you're wrong. Take the case of `sed`. Compare `sed 's/a/b/'` with `echo 's/a/b/' | sed`. What happens? it's not the same thing, right?

Comment: Now if your question is about _How to read from stdin_, then you must have a look at the builtin `read`. You'll have a hard time parsing the input, though. Good luck. Then you're on your own to do the logic to deal with the input from stdin and arguments. Good luck again. At some point, if you have specific questions, feel free to come back and ask these specific questions! `:)`.

Comment: I said _you'll have a hard time parsing the input_ because `echo shell\ script dns` and `echo shell script dns` have the same output. Good luck.

Comment: @chilicuil You might want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6779351/307826) at SO about how to write a small function that reads from stdin (see the `$@` variable) also check [this info](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/scrpt/scrpt2.2.2.html) about special variables

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, I think I've found a good enough solution, I've left it as an answer, feel free to comment if you've a better idea to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the following references:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61183/bash-script-that-reads-filenames-from-a-pipe-or-from-command-line-args
- http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/working-stdin-and-stdout
- http://mockingeye.com/blog/2013/01/22/reading-everything-stdin-in-a-bash-script/

I've edited the above script as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -t 0 ]; then
    #there is input comming from pipe or file, add to the end of $@
    set -- "${@}" $(cat)
fi

[ "${#}" -eq "0" ] && (printf "%s\\n" "${0}: word ..." >&2; exit 1)

_whats()
{
    [ -z "${1}" ] && return 1
    [ -z "${2}" ] && more_than_one="1"

    for word; do
        response="$(dig +short txt ${word}.wp.dg.cx)"
        printf "%s\\n" "${response}"
        if [ -z "${more_than_one}" ]; then
            printf "\\n%s\\n\\n" ":::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"
        fi
    done
}

_whats "${@}"
```

Which will concatenate args + stdin in $@, so now it will work in the following scenarios:

```
whats dns script #it outputs two definitions
echo dns script | whats #same outputs as above
echo dns script | whats ip #outputs ip, dns and script definition in that order
```

It will parse correctly spaces with they came as args

```
whats shell\ script dns #output two definitions
```

But not when those parameters are passed through a pipe:

```
echo shell\ script dns | whats #output three definitions
```

However that's a problem other unix utilities have too (-print0, -0, etc), so I can live with it.